# Specflow - Using Microsoft Dependency Injection from .NET Core leads to BoDi.ObjectContainerException

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, .net-core, specflow

I'm currently trying to setup a new .NET Core Project with Speflow and connect the default Microsoft Dependency Injection to it.

After studying the documentation and the [Autofac](https://github.com/gasparnagy/SpecFlow.Autofac/)/[Ninject](https://github.com/MattMcKinney/SpecFlow.Ninject) implementation I tried to implement my own RunTime plugin "SpecFlow.MSDependencyInjection.SpecFlowPlugin".

Now I'm struggling to resolve Specflow specific infrastructure like the ScenarioContext.

```
    public static class DependencyInjectionExtension
    {
        private static void RegisterSpecflowDependecies(IObjectContainer objectContainer, ServiceCollection serviceCollection)
        {
            serviceCollection.AddSingleton(objectContainer);

            serviceCollection.AddSingleton((x) =>
            {
                var specflowContainer = x.GetRequiredService<IObjectContainer>();
                var scenarioContext = specflowContainer.Resolve<ScenarioContext>();
                return scenarioContext;
            });

            serviceCollection.AddSingleton((x) =>
            {
                var specflowContainer = x.GetRequiredService<IObjectContainer>();
                var scenarioContext = specflowContainer.Resolve<FeatureContext>();
                return scenarioContext;
            });

            serviceCollection.AddSingleton((x) =>
            {
                var specflowContainer = x.GetRequiredService<IObjectContainer>();
                var scenarioContext = specflowContainer.Resolve<TestThreadContext>();
                return scenarioContext;
            });
        }

        [ScenarioDependencies]
        public static IServiceProvider CreateServiceCollection(IObjectContainer objectContainer)
        {
            var serviceCollection = new ServiceCollection();

            RegisterSpecflowDependecies(objectContainer, serviceCollection);

            var bindingAttributeClasses = typeof(DependencyInjectionExtension).Assembly.GetTypes()
                .Where(t => Attribute.IsDefined(t, typeof(BindingAttribute))).ToArray();

            foreach (var bindingAttributeClass in bindingAttributeClasses)
            {
                serviceCollection.AddSingleton(bindingAttributeClass);
            }

            return serviceCollection.BuildServiceProvider();
        }
    }
```

When Specflow is trying to resolve one of my Bindings I get the following exception:

```
BoDi.ObjectContainerException: 'Primitive types or structs cannot be resolved: System.String (resolution path: TechTalk.SpecFlow.ScenarioContext->TechTalk.SpecFlow.ScenarioInfo)'
```

The code of RegisterSpecflowDependecies is very similar to the [Autofac](https://github.com/gasparnagy/SpecFlow.Autofac/) implementation. So I don't understand why it doesn't work in my implementation.

Comment: Did you found any solution for your issue?

Answer (score 0):

It appears that one of the constructors has a string parameter.

You could wrap that constructor in another class that either gets the parameter another way:

```
class MyWrapper : ClassThatHasAStringParameter
{
    public MyWrapper()
       : base("PARAMETER_VALUE")
    {
    }
}
```

Comment: As far as I understand Specflow handles its own dependencies. So I'm not really sure what values have to be inserted inthe the ScenarioContext because it is a Specflow dependency. That is why I used the specific Specflow Objectcontainer that should be able to resolve it. At least that is what I thought... Long story short I don't know what string is expected.